# Best practises for network call request/response in iPhone Application Programming

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have developed 3 Android and 2 Iphone Apps, as I am from the Java background i got
best practises to make network/web service call working on different threads correctly. Making parallel multiple calls other than main thread.

But while going across iOS platform for almost about 2 iphone apps, i have not yet got which
are the best practises for iOS web service call model, so that UI will not be affected.

I have used NSURLConnection and its callback methods.

Can anyone help me out here with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case, I'd evaluate existing 3rd-party networking frameworks/libraries (like with java), before starting from scratch and implementing all by yourself!

Start for example with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
This is one of the most successful ones and uses NSURLConnection with NSOperation (and NSOperationQueue for async requests) etc. under the hood.

**Update**

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire) is the Swift counterpart of AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the request by using NSURLConnection class [this is the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It helped me a lot in request/response for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices generally are in my point of view:

- Use NSURLConnection as much as possible
- When using NSURLConnection, use the asynchronous api, via delegate + a call to 'start', generally from main thread
- When using NSURLConnection, don't use the sendSynchronousRequest
- Parse any incoming data in background, either by using a block and dispatch_async, or any other available APIS in system for concurrency
- Use 3rd party frameworks, as RestKit, if you have a very complicated server API which needs lots of heavy coding for parsing etc, and you don't have time to implement all using NSURLConnection